# Is there a reason for an exterior vent not connected to anything?

Tags: hvac, vent, exterior

I have an exterior vent on the side of my house not connected to any piping within. You can look inside and see wood/concrete/insulation into the cavity between the basement ceiling and main floor. I'm guessing it was an old vent before basement renovations. The dryer and basement bathroom fan both vent to another wall.

After a recent infestation of wasps I want to know if there is any reason I shouldn't just seal it up.

Answer (score 3):

No reason for such an opening.  You should stuff insulation into it and then cap it.  Or, if you have spare siding, remove it and patch the siding.

Comment: That reminds me -- I have such a "dead" vent apparently left over from a previous kitchen exhaust (it's currently behind a cabinet, I think). I should stuff some insulation in that before winter.

Comment: Whenever I go into an old house I buy cans of closed-cell spray foam (e.g., Great Stuff Big Gap Filler) and go around the perimeter of the basement, attic, and wherever else I can access.  Inevitably there are such holes left in the sheathing, sills, and even foundation!  So I spray foam them in to prevent pests from infiltrating and then back that up with appropriate solid insulation.

Comment: Spray foam, used wisely, is good stuff. (Dunno about great -- and yeah, I know it's one of the brand names). And yes, air sealing can make a huge difference in energy efficiency; it's usually the single most effective improvement AND is relatively cheap.